# Is there a way to run a VBA macro on an MS Word document using Python in MacOS?

Tags: python, vba, macos, ms-word

Long-time listener, first-time caller.

I'm trying to find a way to run a VBA macro on a Word document using Python in MacOS.  My searches so far have turned up many solutions that tick 2-3 of those boxes, but nothing that ticks all 4.  The closest I have found is the below code (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065202/run-a-word-vba-macro-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
import os
import comtypes.client

path=r"MyMacro.docm"

word=comtypes.client.CreateObject("Word.Application")
word.Documents.Open(path,ReadOnly=1)
word.Run("'MyDocument.docx'!ThisModule.ThisProcedure"))
word.Documents(1).Close(SaveChanges=0)
word.Application.Quit()
wd=0
```

Unfortunately, this uses `comtypes`, which is Windows-only.

The problem that I'm ultimately trying to solve here is applying conditional coloring to cells of a table in a Word document being generated with the docx-mailmerge package for Python on a MacOS machine.  I already have a VBA macro with which this can be done manually, I'm just trying to figure out if this is something that I can automate.